# Image fitting the height of column in a flex row

Tags: html, css

I have a layout looking like this:

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column-12 {
  width: 50%;
}

.column-12 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="column-12" id="column-1">
    Here are some form fields
  </div>
  <div class="column-12" id="column-2">
    Here should be the image
  </div>
</div>
```

The `column-1` has children that define its height. I want it to be the maximum height a column can get in a `.flex-row` (so `column-2` will never exceed `column-1` height) – this is because I want the image fitted in the `column-2` that will have `height: 100%` so it should match the `column-1` height.

How can I do this? When I put an image into `column-2` and set `max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: 100%; max-height: 100%;` it matches the width, but the image is much taller than the `column-1`.

Comment: *className* doesn't exist in HTML

Comment: @Gerard My bad, coming directly from React with this issue. Fixed in the post!